# How to check if any point (or part) of a line is inside or touches a rectangle

Tags: math, line

I want to check if a line (or any point of a line) is within a rectangle or intersects  a rectangle.

I have (x0, y0) and (x1, y1) as starting and ending points of a line.
Also, (ax,ay) and (bx,by) as the top-left and bottom-right points of a rectangle

For example,

```
     ____________
    |            |
 ---|-----       |    Result: true
    |            |
    |____________|

    /
  _/__________
 |/           |
 /            |      Result: true
/|            |
 |____________|


     ____________
    |            |
    |   -------- |   Result: true
    |            |
    |____________|    ----------     Result: false
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this? I dont want to know which point is that, i just want to know if its there or not.

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: +1 for clear ASCII art :)

Comment: A quick Google for "Cohen Sutherland" should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Consider each edge as it's own line segment. Then it's just a matter of determining line-segment intersection *and* the case where it's entirely contained-in. Of course, this is just a quick observation and likely not the *ideal* way of solving this type of intersection (it's also a really common intersection -- I'd be really surprised if this is an original question ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first and third cases are trivial - simply return true if either endpoint of the line is within the box (i.e. > ax and ay, < bx and by).

The second presents a problem - we can't rely on the endpoints of our line anymore. In this case, we will have to test the line with each edge of the rectangle.

The equation for our line will be `(x1 - x0)*x + (y1 - y0)*y + x0*y0 - x1*y1 = 0` , and we can construct a similar equation for each side of the rectangle using the corners. Following that, substituting the equation for the sides of the rectangle into our line will give us the intersection.

Finally, we check to ensure that the point is within the bounds of the side of the rectangle, and likewise within the line segment we are considering.

There is a more detailed account of this in [this discussion](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/83612-line-intersect-rect/page__view__findpost__p__1422026).

Comment: 2) doesn't seem right to me. take the case of the unit square (0,0 to 1,1) versus the segment (-1,0)-(1,3), for example.

Comment: You're right! That would produce a false positive. I will update my answer.