# Android/Java how to check if a Rectangle and a line segment intersect without line2d

Tags: java, android, intersection, lines

in my game for Android I need to check for intersection between a rectangle and a line segment. I cannot use [line2d](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html) as android does not support that. I have looked at similar questions dealing with lines and tried to modify them and failed. I also realize this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823789/how-to-check-if-any-point-or-part-of-a-line-is-inside-or-touches-a-rectangle) which is basically what I want, however I have failed. For an example here is my code for a Line class that includes my attempt at intersection. The results have been some non-intersections returning true  and some intersections returning false. EDIT: Oli Charlesworth helped me and here is working code for any googlers out there.

```
   package com.example.HelloAndroid;

import android.graphics.Rect;

public class Segment {
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
    double m;
    double b;
    boolean ishoriz;
    boolean isvert;

    public Segment(int x1s, int y1s, int x2s, int y2s) {
        if (x1s > x2s) {
            this.x1 = x2s;
            this.x2 = x1s;
        } else {
            this.x1 = x1s;
            this.x2 = x2s;
        }
        if (y1s > y2s) {
            this.y1 = y2s;
            this.y2 = y1s;
        } else {
            this.y1 = y1s;
            this.y2 = y2s;
        }
        int ydif = y2s - y1s;
        int xdif = x2s - x1s;
        if (ydif == 0) {
            this.ishoriz = true;
            this.m = 0;
            this.b = x1s;
        } else if (xdif == 0) {
            this.isvert = true;
        } else {
            this.m = (double) ydif / xdif;
            double r = (double) ydif / xdif;
            this.b = y1s - (r * x1s);
            this.isvert = false;
            this.ishoriz = false;
        }
    }

    public final boolean intersected(Segment s, Segment s2) {
        if (s.ishoriz && s2.ishoriz) {
            //parallel
            return false;
        }

        if (s.isvert && s2.isvert) {
            //parallel

            return false;
        }

        if (s.isvert) {
            //x is constant see if the x is on the other line
            int x = s.x1;
            //add 2 for round-off error
            if (s2.x1 <= x + 2 && s2.x2 + 2 >= x) {
                //solve and check if y is on both segments
                int y = (int) ((s.m * x) + s.b);
                if(s.y1<=y+2&&s.y2+2>=y)
                {
                    if(s2.y1<=y+2&&s2.y2+2>=y)
                    {
                return true;}
            }
            }
            return false;
        }

        if (s2.isvert) {
            //x is constant see if the x is on the other line
            int x = s2.x1;
            //add 2 for round-off error
            if (s.x1 <= x + 2 && s.x2 + 2 >= x) {
                //solve and check if y is on both segments
                int y = (int) ((s.m * x) + s.b);
                if(s.y1<=y+2&&s.y2+2>=y)
                {
                    if(s2.y1<=y+2&&s2.y2+2>=y)
                    {
                return true;}
            }
            }
            return false;
        }

        if (s.ishoriz) {
            //y is constant see if the y is on the other line
            int y = s.y1;
            //add 2 for round-off error
            if (s2.y1 <= y + 2 && s2.y2 + 2 >= y) {
                //solve and check if x is on both segments
                int x=(int) ((y-s.b)/s.m);
                if(s.x1<=x+2&&s.x2+2>=x)
                {
                    if(s2.x1<=x+2&&s2.x2+2>=x)
                return true;}
            return false;
        }}

        if (s2.ishoriz) {
            //y is constant see if the y is on the other line
            int y = s2.y1;
            //add 2 for round-off error
            if (s.y1 <= y + 2 && s.y2 + 2 >= y) {
                //solve and check if x is on both segments
                int x=(int) ((y-s.b)/s.m);
                if(s.x1<=x+2&&s.x2+2>=x)
                {
                    if(s2.x1<=x+2&&s2.x2+2>=x)
                return true;}
            }
            return false;
        }

        if (s.m == s2.m) {
            //parallel
            return false;
        }

        // use substitution
        // (s.m-s2.m)x=s2.b-s.b
        int x = (int) (s.m - s2.m);
        x = (int) ((s2.b - s.b) / x);
        // find y
        int y = (int) ((x * s.m) + s.b);
        //check if the values are in between for both lines
        //add 2 for round-off error
        if (s.y1 <= y + 2) {
            if (s.y2 + 2 >= y) {
                if (s2.y1 <= y + 2) {
                    if (s2.y2 + 2 >= y) {
                        if (s.x1 <= x + 2) {
                            if (s.x2 + 2 >= x) {
                                if (s2.x1 <= x + 2) {
                                    if (s2.x2 + 2 >= x) {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public final boolean intersects2(Segment s, Rect r) {
        //created lines of the rect
        Segment top = new Segment(r.left, r.top, r.right, r.top);
        Segment left = new Segment(r.left, r.top, r.left, r.bottom);
        Segment bottom = new Segment(r.left, r.bottom, r.right, r.bottom);
        Segment right = new Segment(r.right, r.top, r.right, r.bottom);
        boolean topp = s.intersected(s, top);
        if (topp) {
            return true;
        }
        boolean leftp = s.intersected(s, left);
        if (leftp) {
            return true;
        }
        boolean bottomp = s.intersected(s, bottom);
        if (bottomp) {
            return true;
        }
        boolean rightp = s.intersected(s, right);
        if (rightp) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: So what is the result?  What did you learn when you attempted to debug this?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth The results have been added. If I may ask, what about my question is unclear so I may fix it?

Comment: Typically, if some code is not working, the first thing to do would be to debug the problem, either by running in the debugger, or by adding print statements to observe values of intermediate variables.  Did you do either of these things?

Comment: So what happened when you debugged the intersection logic?

Comment: Although in my test lines my m is initialized the m while in my actual app they aren't, for instance when the x difference is -370 and the y difference is 223 I'm getting a slope or m of 0

Comment: Try declaring all your member variables as `final`.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: When i declare the member variables as final I get an error that they can't be assigned if I assign them while initializing or an error that the variable may have not been initialized.

Comment: Exactly.  Those are almost certainly problems that you should address.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: That makes no sense, you want me to declare it as final and yet be able to reinitialize those variables? Unless I'm missing something that's impossible.

Comment: But why do you need to reassign member variables?  A method such as `intersects` should not need to modify the state of the object.  (BTW, your code snippet is almost impossible to read because it has no indentation.  So it's possible that I'm missing something...)

Comment: @Oli Charlsesworth: When I cleaned up my code I noticed my mistake. I can't thank you enough could you put your last comment as an answer so I may accept and upvote it? For anyone else looking for the method I've added the fixed code to the OP with some comments.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad I could help.  I've put my comments into the form of an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you're not initialising all your member variables correctly.  In general, you should aim to make as many member variables `final` as possible, for (at least) two reasons:

- the compiler will enforce that they must be initialised in the constructor.
- the compiler will prevent you from overwriting them accidentally in a normal member function.

In other words, you should always aim to get the compiler to spot your bugs for you!